# Why is Symbol.iterator visible with getOwnPropertySymbols, but Symbol.hasInstance is not?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Symbol in JS, but I have a question, the sample code is below:

```js
function Func1() { }

Func1[Symbol.iterator] = 111;

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(Func1)); // [ Symbol(Symbol.iterator) ]; it is ok.

/********************/

function Func2() { }

Func2[Symbol.hasInstance] = () => {
  console.log("symbol hasInstance");
  return false;
};

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(Func2)); // []; nothing here, I don't understand.

/********************/

class Baz {
  static [Symbol.hasInstance]() {
    console.log("symbol hasInstance");
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(Baz)); // [ Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance) ]; it is also ok.
```

Could you guys help me? I am very confused. Thanks!

Comment: @Dai It seems that the rule of descriptor does not take effect on symbol？

Comment: if I use `Object.defineProperty` to implement `Symbol.hasInstance` on Func2, it is ok

Comment: It's assigned to the prototype. Just not on the instance. But I don't really see why. See with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(Func2))`

Comment: `Symbol.hasInstance` is an _inherited_ property (from `Function.prototype[Symbol.hasInstance]`). If you set a property that doesn’t exist yet, it becomes an own property; otherwise it gets set wherever it is defined in the prototype chain. If the property exists but wasn’t an own property, then it won’t _become_ an own property just like that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. When I use strict, `Func1[Symbol.hasInstance] = etc` is error, because `Symbol.hasInstance` in `Function.prototype` is non-writable. So I can only reimplement it using `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: When I run `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Function.prototype));`, I solve the problem.